# How to bind combo box in data grid, in .net winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, combobox

i am developing billing software using .net win application. so i need to bind combo box in  grid column1, column2.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess (if I understand you): Set the ColumnSpan Property of the ComboBox to 2.

Comment: i have combo box data source in my data set.. i need to bind it into combo box it is in my data grid. so how to bind it